# Finding out the hashing algorithm and salt if you know the password and the resultant hash

Tags: hash, salt

If I have the password and hash will I be able to find out the Hashing algorithm and salt used. What tools can I can use? Will hashcat work?

Comment: So you're brutal-forcing the salt from a pre-selected hashing algorithms?

Comment: Hash strings often start with an identifier (e.g. `$argon2id$`).

Comment: The hash string usually also includes the salt. It's usually  `$<ALGORITHM_ID>$<DIFFICULTY_PARAMETERS>$<BASE64_ENCODED_SALT><BASE64_ENCODED_HASH>$`.

Comment: If your hash is just the binary output of a PBKDF and the salt is both secret and large enough (i.e. it's really a "pepper")  then finding out the salt and even the algorithm used may be impossible. Generally you can rely on the (meta) information in the hash string as stated above.